# Null desde un lado de relacion belongManyToMany Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, model-view-controller

tengo un problema con las relaciones ManyToMany en Laravel .

Tengo dos modelos que se relacionan con esta opción.

Modelo Patron - Tabla Patrons
 Modelo Atla - Tabla Atlas

En donde estas se relacionan con la tabla Pivot atla_patron.

EL problema es que cuando realizo la consulta desde un lado de la relación, en este caso desde Atla:

```
$atla = Atla::find(1)

$atla->patrons
```

Esta relacion si me da resultados

La inversa:

```
$patron = Patron::find(1)
$patron->atlas
```

Esta opcion me devuelve null.

si me da la opción de ver la tabla pivot y me da resultados con los atributos que se relacionan.
Pero desde el lado del Patron me devuelve null. Adjunto codigo para verificacion. Agradezco las ayudas.

Modelo Patron

```
            namespace App;

        use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

        class Patron extends Model
        {
            protected $guarded = [];


            public function atlas()
            {
                return $this->belongsToMany('App\Atla', 'atla_patron', 'patron_id', 'atla_id');
            }



            public function paciente()
            {
                return $this->belongsTo('App\Paciente');
            }
        }
```

Modelo Atla

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Atla extends Model
    {

        public function patrons()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Patron', 'atla_patron', 'atla_id', 'patron_id');
        }



    }
```

Tabla Atla

```
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('atlas', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->string('name');
            });
        }
```

Tabla Patron

```
      public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('patrons', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->bigInteger('persona_id');
                $table->foreign('persona_id')->references('persona_id')->on('pacientes');

                //Realizar tabla hija
                $table->string('x_supino_izq_1')->nullable(); // V o F si esta selelecionado o no
                $table->string('x_supino_izq_2')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_supino_izq_3')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_supino_izq_4')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_supino_der_1')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_supino_der_2')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_supino_der_3')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_supino_der_4')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_prono_izq_1')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_prono_izq_2')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_prono_izq_3')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_prono_izq_4')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_prono_der_1')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_prono_der_2')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_prono_der_3')->nullable();
                $table->string('x_prono_der_4')->nullable();

                $table->string('giro_cab')->nullable();
                $table->string('pelvis')->nullable();
                $table->string('rest_sacra')->nullable();
                $table->string('fosa_izq')->nullable(); //Valor numerico de 1 a 10 con decimales
                $table->string('fosa_der')->nullable(); //Valor numerico de 1 a 10 con decimales

                $table->string('angular_omop')->nullable();
                $table->string('oblicuo_men')->nullable();
                $table->string('oblicuo_may')->nullable();
                $table->string('ecom')->nullable();
                $table->string('com')->nullable();
                $table->string('recto_post_izq')->nullable();
                $table->string('recto_post_der')->nullable();
                $table->string('inter_trans')->nullable();
                $table->string('espelino_cab')->nullable();
                $table->string('espelino_cue')->nullable();
                $table->string('esc_medio')->nullable();
                $table->string('C3')->nullable();
                $table->string('C4')->nullable();
                $table->string('C5')->nullable();
                $table->string('C6')->nullable();
                $table->string('C7')->nullable();
                $table->string('D1')->nullable();
                $table->string('D2')->nullable();
                $table->string('D3')->nullable();
                $table->string('D4')->nullable();
                $table->string('D5')->nullable();
                $table->string('D6')->nullable();
                $table->string('D7')->nullable();
                $table->string('D8')->nullable();
                $table->string('D9')->nullable();
                $table->string('D10')->nullable();
                $table->string('D11')->nullable();
                $table->string('D12')->nullable();
                $table->string('L1')->nullable();
                $table->string('L2')->nullable();
                $table->string('L3')->nullable();
                $table->string('L4')->nullable();
                $table->string('L5')->nullable();
                $table->string('il_cost')->nullable();
                $table->string('dor_l')->nullable();
                $table->string('ser_p_sup')->nullable();
                $table->string('ser_p_inf')->nullable();
                $table->string('SCMa')->nullable();
                $table->string('SCMe')->nullable();
                $table->string('Lig_si')->nullable();
                $table->mediumText('atlas')->nullable();
                $table->mediumText('axis')->nullable();
                $table->mediumText('inferiores')->nullable();

                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

Tabla atla_patron (pivot)

```
       */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('atla_patron', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->foreign('atla_id')->references('id')->on('atlas');
                $table->foreign('patron_id')->references('id')->on('patrons');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('atla_id');
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('patron_id');

                // $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Probaste si te funciona con eager load en vez de lazy load? `$patron = Patron::with('atlas')->find(1);
$patron->atlas;`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Las opcion que funciona es $patron = Patron::with('atlas')->find(1); Esta opcion si me devuelve la relacacion. Pero al querer acceder a la tabla pivot con $patron->atlas sigue dando null. Es igual como al llamad $patron = Patron::find(1); $patron->atlas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu tabla tienes una columna llamada atlas:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('patrons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // ...
        $table->mediumText('atlas')->nullable();
        // ...
});
```

Y en el modelo defines la relación con el mismo nombre:

```
    class Patron extends Model
    {
        public function atlas()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Atla', 'atla_patron', 'patron_id', 'atla_id');
        }
    }
```

Entonces al hacer:

```
$patron = Patron::find(1);
$patron->atlas;
```

Te trae el resultado de la columna, que seguramente tiene valor `null`, en vez de el resultado de la relación. Cambia el nombre de una de las dos.

Por ejemplo cambiando el nombre de la relación:

```
    class Patron extends Model
    {
        public function atlasRelacionados()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Atla', 'atla_patron', 'patron_id', 'atla_id');
        }
    }
```

y luego la obtienes con:

```
$patron = Patron::find(1);
$patron->atlasRelacionados; // relación
$patron->atlas; // columna
```

O cambiando el nombre de la columna:

```
$table->mediumText('columna_atlas')->nullable();
```

y las obtienes

```
$patron = Patron::find(1);
$patron->atlas; // relación
$patron->columna_atlas; //columna
```

Comment: El error es este que marcaste, habia dos campos con el mismo nombre, y traia la infomacion del campo y no de la relacion. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo pruebas con los datos de las migraciones y modelos que dejastes en la pregunta replique los datos y me dio el mismo error, luego elimine unas columnas de la tabla `patron` y me funciono te coloco el resultado

```php
>>> Patron::find(1)->atlas
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3035
     all: [
       App\Atla {#3036
         id: 1,
         name: "aaaa",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3030
           patron_id: 1,
           atla_id: 1,
         },
       },
     ],
   }
>>>
```

Por lo que puedo sospechar puede ser la cantidad de columnas de tu tabla `patron`, se me ocurre que la dividas en varias tablas

Comment: No veo como tener múltiples columnas sea un error

Comment: Yo tampoco le encuentro lógica estoy buscando información al respecto

Comment: Verificando la relación con el método   $atlas = Atla::withCount('patrons')->get();
    dd($atlas); Me da informacion sobre la relacion. Pero el problema esta al queres recuperara de la manera que informa la documentacion de laravel

Comment: @gonzalobec pero no es la relación `atlas` la que no funciona?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Exacto, solo compruebo si existen las relaciones, los modelos se ven, pero al querer obtener los datos desde $patron->atlas sigue tirando null como resultado. Estoy desconcertado. Al reves la cosa funciona de los mas bien

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Con esta opcion es la que me da como resultado NULL : $patron = Patron::find(1)->atlas;

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Probe con esta opcion que me recomendaste eager load: $patron = Patron::with('atlas')->find(1); $patron->atlas; Lo unico que la relacion con pivot no me la muestra